How to optimize performance for a dynamic grid layout with many expandable items in Flutter?
I'm building a Flutter app where I have a dynamic grid of elements that changes based on screen size. The grid elements are also expandable, meaning their size can change at runtime. I achieved my wanted layout; however, I'm experiencing performance issues when there are a large number of elements — the layout becomes laggy and unresponsive. Here is an Image of my (wanted) layout: 
Here's the current layout implementation:
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    // Determine the number of columns based on the width
    int crossAxisCount = AppDimensions.getCrossAxisCount(constraints.maxWidth);
    double itemWidth = (constraints.maxWidth - (crossAxisCount - 1) * 10) / crossAxisCount;
    return Wrap(
      spacing: 10,
      runSpacing: 10,
      children: provider.polizzenList.map((polizze) {
        return Container(
          width: itemWidth,
          child: PolizzenCard(
            polizze: polizze
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  },
),



Look at the InheritedWidget

I was able to achieve the wanted layout by using the package dynamic_height_grid_view. This seems to also be really efficient in performance.
